# How to run scripts to create and configure a VM from within Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have a large PowerShell script that creates a machine and performs a bunch of configurations and it relies on Az module together with some custom modules I have written. I can run it from my machine, but I am exploring the possibility to run it from Azure and letting others run it without the need to fetch the latest version of the script and the dependent modules.

I have looked into Azure Functions, Logic Apps and Pipelines, but I don't really even know where to start and which one is the most suitable.

The workflow I would like to achieve is this:

- A teammate would specify a machine name and trigger the script.
- The script would then use Az modules and pull some modules from a git repo to create and configure a VM.
- The teammate would receive some sort of feedback to show if the script was successful, maybe a log or an email notification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Runbook running over Automation Account?  You can manage your source with DevOps and use Automation Account' Source Control. You can also use Azure Arc Agent on VM to run your script.